# Top Back Bar Button Item back to previous page in webview

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I am using Xcode to develop webview. I want to do is when i load a webpage, the webpage may will has other page, so i will click the button icon in that website to another page, and i want the one is when click the top back bar button, it will back to every previous page visit and last back to application home page. Now what I do for now is when i click the top back bar button, it directly go to application home page. 
Below is my xcode code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let backarrow = UIImage(named: "navi_back")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backarrow
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backarrow
    if let topItem = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem {
        topItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com")
    myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
}
```

Comment: please give feedback, say this website is help ppl, but already 2 hour, no feedback

Comment: hi
first of all this site really helps people , second i tried to read your problem definition but don't mind me saying your english is so bad with very limited vocabulary this is why no one Actually helped .

now back to your question i added an answer

Answer (score 0):

if i understand Correctly you want back button to go back in webView until there are no pages available for backing then you want to go back to your previous viewController

you need to set an action for your backButton

```
topItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(webViewBack))
```

then check if webview has pages in its back Stack

```
func webViewBack(){
if(myWebView.canGoBack == false)
{
 self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
else{
myWebView.goBack()
}
}
```